# Inputting Numbers Into Empty List Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, input, append, tuples

I'm in the process of writing a program that demonstrates linear search, but I'm stuck with one of the steps I'm taking. In this step, I'm trying to get the program to take an input list of numbers separated by commas, and then return the list in list form.
(ex. 1,5,2,4 --> [1,5,2,4]).
So far, this code I have will return the input in list form, but only if I input a single number. (ex. 3 --> [3]).

```
def main():
    n = eval(input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: "))
    list = []
    n = int(n)
    list.append(n)

    print(list)
main()
```

But when I input a list of numbers with commas, I get this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/eardery/Desktop/Final Exam Practice/linearsearch.py", line 8, in  <module>
  main()
File "C:/Users/eardery/Desktop/Final Exam Practice/linearsearch.py", line 4, in main
   n = int(n)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

What's another way to evaluate the input without getting this error and have the program do as I intended it to work? And could somebody explain what a 'tuple' is?

Comment: look what `n` contains ;-)

Comment: _Please_ don't use `list` as variable name. There is a built-in stuff with that name.

Comment: The `eval` actually did the work for you, and `n` is a tuple of `int`s.  But really, you should take the advice of the answerers below, and not use `eval` on user input.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `eval` here. `eval` is best avoided when working with user input. Also it will often return unexpected results, as in your case, when it handles lists of integers differently than single integers.)

How about something like this:

```
line = input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: ")
data = [int(i) for i in line.split(',')]
```

The last line will split the text around the commas and cast each element into an int. It is equivalent to

```
data = []
for i in line.split(','):
    data.append(int(i))
```

Comment: Note: He is obviously using Python 3, so it should be `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sir. Old habits die hard. I have adapted appropriately.

Comment: It worked! I see what mistakes I made now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Tuple is a immutable (un-changable) list.  This is what Python is assuming you entered, because it is a comma separated list.

`split(',')` allows you to break `'1,2,3'` into `['1', '2', '3']` and will convert '4' into ['4']

You still need to convert each string to int, and I'm doing a list comprehension for that.

```
def main():
    n = input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: ")
    # For each val in list of input, make int.
    list = [int(val) for val in n.split(',')]
    print(list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need eval function. It is only for evaluating the stuffs.

You need to split the output by split function and dump it into list.

Your solution:-

```
def main():
    n = raw_input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: ")
    list= [int(value) for value in n.split(',')]
    print(list)
main()
```

Comment: this doesn't convert the strings to ints.

Comment: You can type cast by int() :)

Comment: Don't use list, it's an built-in type. the fisrt assignment to `list` is useless.

Comment: I kept it intentionally for him to understand. I know without declaring vairable it can be achievable

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    n = list(input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: "))
    n = map(lambda x:int(x),n)
    print( n)
main()
```

Comment: you can't. You only get a list of single characters.

Comment: This only returns a list of strings.  Has to be converted to ints.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `eval` cause eval is evil.

```
def main():
    raw = input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: ")
    numbers = list(map(int, raw.split(',')))
    print(numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hey, -2? why? comment please!

Comment: Most likely because `list(map(int, raw.split(',')))` is not as Pythonic as `[int(val) for val in raw.split(',')]`.  In addition, optimization with list comprehensions generally make them faster than `list` and `map`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I assume that is why.  I find the list comprehension much easier to read quickly.